# Tensorflow CSV pipeline is too slow

Tags: csv, tensorflow, queue, pipeline

I had read csv file using tf.TextLineReader
I used GPU (GTX1050TI)
When I used batch size 1, It takes 65% LOAD.
But I used batch size 100, It takes just 10% GPU load.

```
1 Row datasize is 24X60Xfloat32 = 5760Bytes
```

so I check that how many times to execute code

when batch size is 1

```
min_after_dequeue = 100
capacity = min_after_dequeue + 3 * batch_size
```

example_batch,

```
label_batch = sess.run([examples, labels]) takes 20ms
sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={X:example_batch, Y:label_batch, p_keep_conv: 0.8, p_keep_hidden: 0.5}) takes 60ms
```

when batch size is 100

```
min_after_dequeue = 200
capacity = min_after_dequeue + 3 * batch_size
```

example_batch,

```
label_batch = sess.run([examples, labels]) takes 5.7s
sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={X:example_batch, Y:label_batch, p_keep_conv: 0.8, p_keep_hidden: 0.5}) 
takes 22ms
```

example_batch,

```
label_batch = sess.run([examples, labels]) execution time increased 300 times.
```

100 Rows data is just 50Mb and I used SSD for data.
I don't understand why it takes too much time for read data.

this is my file read code.

```
def read_my_file_format(filename_queue):

    reader = tf.TextLineReader(skip_header_lines=1)    

    _, value = reader.read(filename_queue)

    record_defaults = [[1],[1],[1], ... ,[1],[1],[1]] # it is 1440 columns

    Col1, Col2, .... , Col1622,Col1623=tf.decode_csv(value, record_defaults=record_defaults)record_defaults=record_defaults)

    features = tf.stack([[[Col4],[Col5], ...., [Col1618],[Col1619],[Col1620]]])

    label = tf.stack([Col29])  

    return features, label  

def input_pipeline(batch_size, num_epochs):

    min_after_dequeue = 10000
    capacity = min_after_dequeue + 3 * batch_size + 20000
    #capacity = 100000
    filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(["dataset_n_day_2.csv"], num_epochs=num_epochs, shuffle=True, capacity=capacity )


    example, label = read_my_file_format(filename_queue)     


    example_batch, label_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch([example, label], 
                                                         batch_size=batch_size, 
                                                         capacity=capacity, 
                                                         min_after_dequeue=min_after_dequeue) 

    return example_batch, label_batch   


examples, labels = input_pipeline(1,5)

i = 0

init_op = tf.group(tf.global_variables_initializer(), tf.local_variables_initializer())

sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))

merged = tf.summary.merge_all()
trainwriter =tf.summary.FileWriter("./board/custom", sess.graph)

sess.run(init_op)

coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)

try:

    while not coord.should_stop():
        i = i + 1        
        st = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        print("#1:", st)
        example_batch, label_batch = sess.run([examples, labels]) 

        st = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        print("#2:", st)       

        sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={X:example_batch, Y:label_batch, p_keep_conv: 0.8, p_keep_hidden: 0.5})  

        st = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')      
        print("#3:", st)

        if i % 1 == 0:
            summary = sess.run(merged, feed_dict={X: example_batch, Y: label_batch, p_keep_conv: 1, p_keep_hidden: 1})
            trainwriter.add_summary(summary,i)  
            print(cost.eval(feed_dict={X: example_batch, Y: label_batch, p_keep_conv: 1, p_keep_hidden: 1}, session = sess))        

except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
    print('Done training -- epoch limit reached')
finally:
    # When done, ask the threads to stop.
    coord.request_stop()  

# Wait for threads to finish.
coord.join(threads)

sess.close()
```

Comment: I think the simple answer here is that TensorFlow's CSV parsing op is not well optimized for the case where there is a large number of columns: the overhead most likely comes from the marshalling of many "record defaults" into the op, and the production of many small tensors each time you run the op. It's easy to imagine a more efficient version that extracts a sequence of columns (as you seem to have here) as a single 1-D tensor. This would make a great [feature request](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues)!

Comment: Thanks. for this reason I convert to my csv file to tfrecords format.